# flutter : String is not passed to "saveName". I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how

Tags: sharedpreferences

```
    void iniState(SharedPreferences prefs) {
    super.initState();
    _retrieveName(prefs);
  }

  String saveName = '' ;

  Future<void> _retrieveName(SharedPreferences prefs) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!prefs.containsKey('name')) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      saveName = prefs.getString('name');
    });
       print(saveName);
  }
```

...

```
                   else {
                  _savedName(_usersemail.text);

                  nvState.setState(() {
                    nvState.navip = 1;
                  },
                  );
                }
```

When "saveName" comes out well on the console and saves and retrieves are considered to be doing well.
However, it is not delivered to "String saveName". What can I do?

I solved it myself. You have successfully modified all your code in a different way.

The entire code was long, so I only wrote the modified part.

Modified code

```
  String _id = '';
  String _pw = '';
  SharedPreferences _prefs;
```

...

```
  final _usersemail = TextEditingController();
  final _userspass = TextEditingController();
```

...

```
  void initState(){
  super.initState();
  _loadID();
  }
```

...

```
 _loadID() async{
 _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 setState(() {
 _id = (_prefs.getString('id') ?? '');
 _pw = (_prefs.getString('pw') ?? '');
 print(_id);
 print(_pw);
 });
 }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

...

```
Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
child: TextFormField(
controller: _usersemail,
```

...

```
 }
 else {
 _id = _usersemail.text;
 _pw = _userspass.text;
 _prefs.setString('id', _id);
 _prefs.setString('pw', _pw);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say its "not delivered to `String saveName`"? How are you checking the value of `saveName`? Does the `print` statement print anything to the console?

Comment: I solved it. I made a different code.Thank you for your interest.